# Difference between java bounded generics vs strategy pattern

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, generic-programming, strategy-pattern

I have a util class which is coupled with interface Isupplier.

Class `Util<T extends Isupplier>`

it has a method execute which has a list of objects which implements Isupplier.

```
execute(List<T extends Isupplier> objList )
```

There are classes which implements the methods in Isupplier. And a caller class, which calls execute method for each of the implementation class.

`Class A implements Isupplier`

`Class B implements Isupplier`

```
 Class ACaller{
 //calls Util.execute(List of Object A)`
}
```

```
 Class BCaller{
 //calls Util.execute(List of Object B)`
}
```

Can this be called usage of strategy pattern? Since we are coding to an interface. The strategy can be implementation of Isupplier. Base Strategy as Isupplier. Context as Util?

Comment: Please show the utility class. It is unclear why a utility would need a generic type, since utilities are typically stateless and non-instantiable. In general, utility classes are not object oriented, and thus not an object-oriented design pattern.

Comment: Actually, you can substitute the util with any random class generator. The main question is whether or not the above design be an example of strategy  pattern

Comment: What is a random class generator? There is not enough information here to judge any design. Please show enough code to execute.

Comment: The strategy pattern is when an algorithm uses an object knowing only that it implements some interface. The algorithm can be applied to any object implementing said interface. So one could say that although your example is not the strategy pattern, it does use the strategy pattern.

Comment: @MauricePerry you have mentioned both things. It is not and it uses strategy pattern. Can you please clarify on this?

Answer (score 0):

Definition: "Strategy is a behavioral design pattern that turns a set of behaviors into objects and makes them interchangeable inside original context object. Also, it is a design pattern that enables an algorithm’s behavior to be selected at runtime."

Rephrasing.. this is usually done by an interface which holds a method and there are some implementing classes each having some different flavor (impl logic) to that. Then there is the client code which can drive algorithm behavior based on the implementing classes.

The following can be an small eg. of it,

```
interface Printer {
    void print();
}   

class LaserPrinter implements Printer {
    void print() {
        Sysout("laser printed");
    }
}

class InkjetPrinter implements Printer {
    void print() {
        Sysout("ink printed");
    }
}

class Client {
    Printer printer;
    if laserprinter
         printer = new LaserPrinter();
    else
         printer = new InkjetPrinter();
}
```

Note 1: **This is a just a snippet, not a concrete eg. and usually strategy can be achieved even without if-else or switch when an setter is used thereby the algorithm behavior will be changed.**

Now to answer your question: **YES**, your eg. uses strategy pattern.

Your class A and class B implements ISupplier, thereby they will add their own flavor to the method 'execute' and your class Util is just a wrapper to that, hence you are changing the behavior of execute method at runtime.

Note 2: As mentioned by jaco0646 Util classes are not object oriented and so you can have a class with a setter accepting concrete objects of ISupplier and that can be used decide what execute must do.

Ref:

1. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strategy-pattern-set-1/
2. https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy/java/example

Regards,
Sabareesh M

Comment: Another good (well-known) example:  a LayoutManager is a good Java example of a Strategy Pattern. If you choose GridBagLayout it arranges the values differently than a FlowLayout for example.

A "strategy" is a way of encapsulating an algorithm that you use for something. Like an layout, an encryption algorithm, etc..

Answer (score 0):

### Response for your first question *"Difference between java bounded generics vs strategy pattern"*

Definition of each concept:

- **Java bounded generics**: Is a tool for restricting the types that can be used as type arguments in a parameterized class or method, ensuring the safe type execution on compilation time. In your case, you're forcing the argument to be extend from Isupplier.
- **Strategy pattern**: Is a behavioral design pattern that turns a set of behaviors into classes which implement the same interface(reling on polymorphism but that does not mean that they are the same thing) and makes them interchangeable inside original context class at runtime, [benefiting the composition over inheritance](https://dzone.com/articles/composition-vs-inheritance).

So now it is clear that [Java bounded generics](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/04/what-is-bounded-and-unbounded-wildcards.html#:%7E:text=bounded%20and%20unbounded%20wildcards%20in%20generics%20are%20used%20to%20bound,be%20upper%20bounded%20by%20using%20%3C%3F&text=super%20T%3E%20where%20all%20Types,similar%20to%20Object%20in%20Java.) is a tool for getting [parametric polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism), ensuring that a parameter implements or extends a concrete class/interface, which has nothing to do with a [Strategy pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy/java/example#:%7E:text=Strategy%20in%20Java,delegates%20it%20executing%20the%20behavior.), it is a useful technique for choosing at runtime which behavior/class is going to be executed.

### Response for your second question
**"The strategy can be implementation of Isupplier. Base Strategy as Isupplier. Context as Util?"**

You're **not** using the strategy pattern(that relies on polymorphism).
I know you could have classes implementing the same Isupplier interface, using polymorphism, but the main difference between the strategy pattern and what you're doing in your method:

```
execute(List<T extends Isupplier> objList)
```

Is that strategy pattern would choose between the objList objects, based on same condition at runtime, and it would execute the choosen one, but only one, not executing the full list of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your case in the example looks more of a case of `Decorator Pattern`  than the Strategy Pattern.

In order to establish the difference between the two, I refer you to a good source ( don't think that I have no idea of my own, but wikipedia is a good reputable source) ;

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

I have actually turned your case into actual running code, below.
I will also try clarify why this is not a Strategy pattern.

```
ISupplier.java:
public interface ISupplier {
  void supply() ;
}

A.java
public class A implements ISupplier {

    private String name = null ;
    public A(String supplierName) {
         name = supplierName;
     }
    public  void supply() {
        System.out.println( name+ " Supplies from China!" );
     }
}


Util.java
import java.util.*;
public class Util <T extends ISupplier> {

 public  void supply() {
    System.out.println( " Util Context!" );
 }
 
 public void execute(List<ISupplier> objList ) {
     for (ISupplier supplier : objList) {
         supplier.supply();
     }
 }
}

ACaller.java
import java.util.*;

public class ACaller {

    Util util =  null;

    List<A> listOfA = null;
    
    public ACaller(Util ut) {
        util = ut;
    }
    
    public void fillListA() {
        listOfA = new ArrayList<A>();
        
        listOfA.add(new A("A-1"));
        listOfA.add(new A("A-2"));
    }
    public void run()  {

        util.execute(listOfA);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Util strategy1 = new Util();
        ACaller ac = new ACaller(strategy1);
        
        ac.fillListA();
        
        ac.run();
        
    }
}
```

When you run this code; you will get:

```
 $ java ACaller 
 A-1 Supplies from China!
 A-2 Supplies from China!
```

The Util class has not provided anything gainful rather than acting as another static intermediary between the Callers and the Suppliers.

In a real functioning Strategy pattern, we would expect the Context  (Util) to dynamically provide a different supply() approach for the solution ..

In other words, we don't have a way of providing a dynamic  implementation of supply() method *from* the Util class.

In short, your case seems to be closer to the Decorator Pattern, than Strategy Pattern , therefore not a Strategy Pattern.

Please note that, both patterns use interfaces, so just because you are writing to an interface, doesn't mean that..

Cheers

Comment: Wikipedia is often a very poor [source](https://twitter.com/ploeh/status/1175820397306109952) for design patterns.